Make sure dropzone works across multiple conversation threads
I'm creating a chatting application with Django Channels and JavaScript. I have multiple conversation threads, each containing a chat form. I tried to make Dropzone work for all the threads by selecting all elements with the attribute [data-dropzone-area] and initializing Dropzone for each one separately. Despite that, it only seems to work for the first thread
const dropzoneAreas = document.querySelectorAll("[data-dropzone-area]");
dropzoneAreas.forEach(function(dropzoneArea) {
    const ti = new oi.Dropzone(dropzoneArea, {
        url: "/",
        clickable: "#dz-btn"
        , previewsContainer: "#dz-preview-row"
        , previewTemplate: '\n<div class="theme-file-preview position-relative mx-2">\n    <div class="avatar avatar-lg dropzone-file-preview">\n        <span class="avatar-text rounded bg-secondary text-body file-title">\n            <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="css-i6dzq1"><path d="M13 2H6a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v16a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V9z"></path><polyline points="13 2 13 9 20 9"></polyline></svg>\n        </span>\n    </div>\n\n    <div class="avatar avatar-lg dropzone-image-preview">\n        <img src="#" class="avatar-img rounded file-title" data-dz-thumbnail="" alt="" >\n    </div>\n\n    <a class="badge badge-circle bg-body text-white position-absolute top-0 end-0 m-2" href="#" data-dz-remove="">\n        <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="css-i6dzq1"><line x1="18" y1="6" x2="6" y2="18"></line><line x1="6" y1="6" x2="18" y2="18"></line></svg>\n    </a>\n</div>\n',
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRFToken': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
        },
        init: function () {
            const dropzoneInstance = this;
            const sendButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.group-send-btn, .direct-send-btn');
            sendButtons.forEach(function (button) {
                button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault()
                    e.stopPropagation()

                    dropzoneInstance.processQueue();
                });
            });
    
        }

    });
    ti.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData) {
        const thread = document.querySelector('.main.active');
        const messageInput = thread.querySelector('.chat_message');
        const message = messageInput.value;
        const threadId = thread.getAttribute('data-thread-id');
        const groupId = thread.getAttribute('data-group-id');

        if (message !== "") {
            formData.append('message', message);
        }
        if (groupId) {
            formData.append('groupId', groupId);
        }

        if (threadId) {
            formData.append('threadId', threadId);

        }
    })
    ti.on("addedfile", (function (e) {
        let o = document.querySelectorAll(".theme-file-preview");
        o = o[o.length - 1].querySelectorAll(".file-title");
        for (let i = 0; i < o.length; i++) o[i].title = e.name
    })), ti.on("success", function (e) {
        const thread = document.querySelector('.main.active');
        const messageTextarea = thread.querySelector('.chat_message');
        messageTextarea.value = "";
        ti.removeAllFiles();
    }), ti.on("addedfiles", (function (e) {
        ti.previewsContainer.classList.add("dz-preview-moved", "pb-10", "pt-3", "px-2")
    })), ti.on("reset", (function (e) {
        ti.previewsContainer.classList.remove("dz-preview-moved", "pb-10", "pt-3", "px-2")
    }))
});

Each thread is iterated over individually in the html like this:
<div class="main conversation-thread d-none" data-dropzone-area="" data-thread-id="{{ group.id }}">
    <!-- Thread content -->

<!-- Chat form-->
<div class="chat-form reverse-rounded-pill bg-dark" data-sender-id="{{ request.user.id }}" data-emoji-form="">
       <div class="chat-form-hr"></div>
       <div class="row align-items-center gx-0">
           <div class="col-auto">
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-icon btn-link text-body rounded-circle" id="dz-btn">
                   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"    stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"    stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-paperclip"><path    d="M21.44 11.05l-9.19 9.19a6 6 0 0 1-8.49-8.49l9.19-9.19a4 4 0 0 1
   5.66 5.66l-9.2 9.19a2 2 0 0 1-2.83-2.83l8.49-8.48"></path></svg>
               </a>
               <form method="POST" id="group-upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                   {% csrf_token %}
                   <input type="hidden" class="group_id" value="{{ group.id }}">
                   <input multiple=True type="file" class="up-hidden-input" tabindex="-1" style="visibility: hidden;    position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 0px; width: 0px;">
               </form>
           </div>
   
           <div class="col">
               <div class="input-group">
                   <textarea class="form-control px-0 chat_message" placeholder="Type your message..." rows="1" data-emoji-input=""    data-autosize="true"></textarea>
   
                   <a href="#" class="input-group-text text-body pe-0" data-emoji-btn="">
                       <span class="icon icon-lg">
                           <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"    stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"    stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-smile"><circle cx="12"    cy="12" r="10"></circle><path d="M8 14s1.5 2 4 2 4-2    4-2"></path><line x1="9" y1="9" x2="9.01" y2="9"></line><line x1="15"    y1="9" x2="15.01" y2="9"></line></svg>
                       </span>
                   </a>
               </div>
           </div>
   
           <div class="col-auto">
               <button class="btn btn-icon btn-primary rounded-circle ms-5 group-send-btn">
                   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"    stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"    stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-send"><line x1="22"    y1="2" x2="11" y2="13"></line><polygon points="22 2 15 22 11 13 2 9    22 2"></polygon></svg>
               </button>
           </div>
       </div>    </div>    </div>

In this setup, I'm looping through each thread for every member
